# Parallel await calls of the same function override each other - Javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, fetch, event-loop

I wrote an API which gets called by multiple clients and computes their request. It roughly look like this:

```
async function main(request){
    url =  //extractUrlFromRequest
    answer = await compute(url)
}

async function compute(url){
    answer = await fetch(url)
    //other computations
    return answer
}
```

Keep in mind that the `main` function can be called multiple times per second or even at the same time by different clients and the computation time of the `compute` function may vary per request (up to ~2 seconds).

**The Problem**

The problem is that if a `compute()` call isn't finished **before** the next `compute()` call arrives the `fetch()` of the second call will override the `fetch()` of the first call no matter where in the code it currently is (The parameters in the header i.e. `url` do not change).

**Example - Expected behavior**

1. `compute()` gets called the first time -> `fetch()` returns "hello"
   -> continues computation
2. `compute()` gets called the second time -> `fetch()` returns "world"
   -> continues computation
3. first `compute()` finishes -> returns "hello"
4. second `compute()` finishes -> returns "world"

**Example - Observed behavior**

1. `compute()` gets called the first time -> `fetch()` returns "hello"
   -> continues computation
2. `compute()` gets called the second time -> `fetch()` returns "world" **and** replaces "hello" of the first call with "world"
   -> continues computation
3. first `compute()` finishes -> returns "world"
4. second `compute()` finishes -> returns "world"

What can i do to achieve the expected behavior?

**What i've tried**

I have read [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) that `Promise.all` can be used to run multiple promises / awaits at once, however this isnt exactly my usecase since i dont have every request at the beginning, but they rather come in one after another and call the `main()` function again.

I've read that javascript is fundamentally single-threaded / linear, is it even possible to achieve the expected results, or did i choose the wrong language for this project?

Comment: Can you show the code of `compute`? Are there any side effects in this function? There is nothing wrong with the code you provided and normally it should just work.

Comment: Unfortunately i cant directly show it, however it is mostly linear code with lots of `if's` and a json it builds in the end, depending on the answer. Im not sure what you mean by side effects but i don't think there are any major ones, since it is pretty straight forward (but also kinda long).
The `if's` and json are also the problematic part however: I.e.: For `if(answer.test)` may be true for the first `fetch` but false for the second `fetch` and break the code if answer changes while already being inside the `if`-condition.

Comment: so you have some state stored somewhere?

Comment: my guess is that you have state somewhere stored outside of the function which would belong inside the function

Comment: I dont think so, the function is linear and shouldnt interact in any way with prior calls.

Comment: Everything i use within the function at most receives information from other function but has no way to write or interact in another way with these function

Comment: `url` and `answer` should be declared as local variables. Not adding `const` or `var` makes them (shared) globals.

Comment: @TobiasS. The code i provided is pretty much the reduced example. Adding a sleep timer below "other computation" when encountering a specific url i.e. "testUrl" and while its in the sleep running the second call archieves this.

Comment: @GOTO0 Wait, that seems to do the trick. Let me test some more then i can be sure!

Comment: It did work! Thanks! You can write it as answer so i can endorse it if you want.

Comment: @NicO never mind :) I'm happy to hear that I could help.